# Is there a name for the combined stats of Balls, Strikes, and Outs, as seen on many displays in baseball?

Tags: baseball, statistics, terminology

Baseball fields often have a display of the number of balls, strikes, and outs.  Does this group have a name?  As far as I can cell, "Count" refers to just balls and strikes and are for individual batters; there are no outs.  An "umpire indicator" often displays innings as well as those three.  Is there a specific name that refers to just BSO?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no name for this particular trio of values.